# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: store is undefined in quasar v2 with vue-routisan and vuex

Tags: quasar-framework, vuex4

currenly i am setting up project using quasar v2, vue-routisan and vuex 4.i I have tried importing useStore and importing from default store but it seems to be not working.been a day trying to figure out the issue.

routes.js

```js
import Route from "vue-routisan";
import {guest} from "./middleware/index";
Route.setViewResolver(component => require("src/pages/" + component).default);
Route.view("/admin", "layouts/Auth")
    .guard(guest)
    .children(() => {
    });
export default Route.all();

guest.js

import { useStore } from 'vuex';
// import store from '../../store'
const store = useStore();

export default async function (to, from, next) {
    
    store.dispatch("auth/fetch")
      .then(r => {
        if (r.status === 200) {
          next("/dashboard");
        } else {
          next();
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        next();
      });
    
}

store/index.js
import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

import currentUser from './auth';

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Store instance.
 */

export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      currentUser
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode and --debug builds only
    // strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store
})
```

error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: store is undefined (at guest.js 7):
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the store in your app
Look for your .quasar folder and inside the app.js file, add this

```
app.use(store)
```

This worked for me